# Show TV program in Samsung SmartTV app

Tags: samsung-smart-tv, television, smart-tv

I'm thinking of an app for Samsung SmartTV which, besides other information, displays the currently running TV program.
Since I haven't found any documentation about accessing and displaying the TV program inside of an app, I was wondering if this is even possible. Has anybody further information?

Thanks,
Markus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to show TV signal inside your SmartTv application. Guide to do that can be found here: http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/tec00103/index.html

However, make sure you read the note at the end of that guide. Mixing TV signal and app content needs approval from broadcasters, which can result in locking your app for only a specific TV channel. It goes the same for ticker applications.

Answer (score 0):

Be really aware about the fact that in EU you cannot overlay even part of the screen of the broadcasted channel by TV application content -> such an application will not approved by TV vendors unless it is for specific channel only for which you must have an agreement - but this is typically more task for a HbbTV...

That regulation is quite limiting - because otherwise you can have nice eweather or sport betting widgets overlaying the screen during e.g. tennis or football match. I am however not sure about similar restrictions on other markets like e.g. MENA or Latin America.

BR

STeN

www.mautilus.com/blog

Comment: So basically it should be ok if I display the TV signal in my TV-app without any kind of overlay, but show additional synchronized information on a tablet computer with a second screen app. Am I right?

Comment: This is absolutely okay. You can also make the TV view with broadcast smaller and display additional information next or below it. The problem is only direct overlay.

Comment: Thanks STeN for your detailed information. Since I have to explain the discussed overlay regulation could you give me any sources? I did some research but haven't found any policy regarding this regulation.

Comment: Hi, see e.g. http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/tec00124/index.html, it mentions that ticker apps are allowed only for US and Korean market. I am not sure if the limitation is that hard - I think it might be allowed in other countries as well, but most probably not EU. The best way to follow is contacting the local Samsung representatives. BR STeN